# Business time difference between datetime objects in Python

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, date-difference

How do I find the business time difference between two datetime objects in Python?

Business time can be 9-17

I want also to consider holidays. I have a function `is_holiday(date)` that takes a date object.

Comment: Have you considered using `datetime.timedelta`? You should post some example code of what you've tried so far to get more help.

Comment: it seems [`businesstime` package does exactly what you want (I haven't used it).](https://github.com/seatgeek/businesstime)

Answer (score 0):

```
def buisiness_time_between(datetime1, datetime2):
    return business_time_after(datetime1) +
        (business_time_per_day * days_between(datetime1,datetime2)) +  
        business_time_before(datetime2)
```

I'm sure you can figure out how to implement `business_time_after`, `business_time_before`, `business_time_per_day`, and `days_between`

Answer (score 0):

I did not really find a simple pythonic answer to this problem.

The package [businesstime](https://github.com/seatgeek/businesstime) suggested by [J.F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian) does what I wanted, but I think that the algorithms can be optimized and simplified. 
For example, if we change the model of the day we can use the standard python datetime operations.

**I try to be clearer**: if our work day is 9-17 we may say that our day is made by 8h and not 24h. So, 9:00->0:00 and 17:00->08:00. Now what we have to do is to create a function that converts the real time inside our new model in this way:

- if it is a time lower than our start time (09:00), we don't care about it and we convert it to 00:00
- if it is a business time we convert subtracting the start time, for example 13:37 becomes 04:37
- if it is a time greater than our stop time (17:00), we don't care about it and we convert it to 08:00

After this conversion all the calculation can be made easily with the python datetime package as you do with a normal datetime.

Thanks also to the answer of [user2085282](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2085282/user2085282) you can find this concept implemented in the repo [django-business-time](https://github.com/mariuccio/django-business-time).

With the model conversion, I found extremely easy to add another feature: **the lunch break**

In fact, if you have a lunch break 12-13, you can map in your new day model all the times inside the interval to 12. **But** pay attention to convert also the time after 13 considering one hour of lunch break.

I am sorry that what I developed is just a Django application and not a Python package. But for the moment, it works for me. And sorry also for my code, I am a newbie :)

PS: the full documentation is coming soon!